# group rows in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve the following in bootstrap but seems that I can't.
I dont know how can i make the big div in this case
Any help?! Thanks!

My idea code is to create rows and "glue" them together:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="ele.jpg" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Big div</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">Empty</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Idea]

Comment: You mean you need to have equal height columns?

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the 30px gutter between columns in Bootstrap. Having this is good for text (as you want some distance between the text two columns), but might be unwanted for an image. You have two options:

1. Use a `no-padding` helper class to remove the padding on the `.col-sm-1`.

```css
.no-padding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 no-padding">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Big div</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">Empty</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Use a helper class that sets a negative margin to offset the `padding` used to create half of the gutter, so a negative margin of `-15px`. Add that `.offset-gutter` class to a `<div>` wrapping the `<img>`.

```css
.offset-gutter {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <div class="offset-gutter">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">Big div</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">Empty</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank your for the no padding idea it is helpful but I'm trying to create the big div by having 2 rows together, as in the picture I need 2 images divided and a big div to show some information!

or have the columns bigger meaning the container has more height! don't know if i am clear though?!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for equal height between the amount of `images` and `Big div` you could do the following.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" >
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" >
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-7 clearfix">Big div</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">Empty</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just make sure to add `.clearfix` class to `Big div` so that `Empty div` will stay in the normal flow when the screen gets smaller. If you also want to get rid of padding use the helper classes mentioned by ckuijjer.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks it is helpful but I want the listing to happen without being depended on the images, meaning images and the big div are separated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sequence I came up with. Not sure how right it is.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
          <div style="background-color: blue;">pic1</div>
          <div style="background-color: red;">pic2</div>       
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-7 offset-gutter" style="background-color:orange;">Big div<br>....</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:green;">Empty<br>...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then use @ckuijjer's offset-gutter class as per below

```
.offset-gutter {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```